# infer_schema function on files with missing column header

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, snowflake-stage

Currently, I have 5 files staged that are all missing one column header:

|  | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | 54.9 | 55.3 | 55.7 |
| Group B | 91.3 | 82.7 | 89.6 |

I cannot change the format of these files. I used the infer_schema function in Snowflake since the files will be dynamic as more year columns get added.

This is what I thought to try:

```
Create or replace table staging_table
     using template (
         select array_agg(object_construct(*))
           from table(
              infer_schema(
                 location => 'stage'
                   file_format => 'file_format'
                     )
                      )
                           );

copy into staging_table
from @stage
file_format = 'file_format'
match_by_column_name = case_insensitive;
```

I'm using a staging table because I also want to unpivot the data. I used `parse_header = true` at first in the file_format, but that didn't work because of the missing header. I tried `parse_header = false` but that makes keeping track of columns and renaming them harder (there's more date columns than the ones in the example). Does anyone have any ideas of how to better handle this case?

Also, I know this might be a long stretch, but I also want to get the file names in the table. I know I can get the file name like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE (
    INFER_SCHEMA(
      LOCATION => MY_STAGE,
        FILE_FORMAT => 'MY_FILE_FORMAT'
        )
     );
```

But how do I actually insert/copy into my staging table along with the data?

In other words, I want data in Snowflake like this:

| Group | Year | Score | File_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | 2021 | 54.9 | File1 |
| Group A | 2022 | 55.7 | File1 |
| Group A | 2023 | 55.7 | File1 |
| Group A | 2021 | 33.1 | File2 |
| Group A | 2022 | 33.1 | File2 |
| Group A | 2023 | 34.2 | File2 |

How do I get from the first file format to the second table format in Snowflake?

Any help would be appreciated!!!! Do I have to break this up into 5 different staging tables and then do one big insert to the real table?

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Schema inference probably is not going to solve it. With the answer to this question, I (or someone who beats me to it) can give you a way to do this. Is the schema regular in the sense that it always has groups (or some string) in the leftmost column (except the top row), year numbers in the top row (except the leftmost column in this row is blank) and the intersection of years and groups is always a number? Also, I assume the number of years may be variable?

Comment: @GregPavlik Yes, the schema is regular. The leftmost column is always a string column with the different groups in there with the header missing. The top row always has years, with the number increasing over time as more yearly data is added. The intersection of years and groups is always a number. The file is automatically generated, so I cannot change the schema.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, the approach is:

1. Read each file in the stage line by line (use a file format that does not specify a column delimiter).
2. Use a UDTF (User Defined Table Function) that knows the first line of each  file is a list of years. The UDTF I supplied will strip off a leading comma for an empty column on this line if it exists.
3. Run the lines for each file through the UDTF. The UDTF will read the years on the first line of each file and pivot the scores to those years.

First, create a file format that reads in ***whole lines***, not individual fields:

```
create or replace file format READ_LINE type = csv 
field_delimiter = 'NONE' compression = 'AUTO';
```

You can then make sure this works to read whole lines by performing a select:

```
select metadata$file_row_number, metadata$filename, $1 as LINE
from @MY_FILES (file_format => READ_LINES);
```

Next, create the UDTF that handles how your data arrives in the files:

```
create or replace function PIVOT_SCORES(LINE_NUMBER float, FILENAME string, LINE string)
returns table (GROUP_NAME string, YEAR string, SCORE string)
language javascript strict immutable
as 
$$
{
    initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {
        this.years = [];
    },
    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
        var lineYear;
        var lineItems;
        if(row.LINE_NUMBER == 1) {
            if(row.LINE.trim().substr(0,1) == ",") {
                this.years = row.LINE.trim().substr(1).split(",");
            } else {
                this.years = row.LINE.trim().split(",");
            }
        } else {
            lineItems = row.LINE.trim().split(",");
            for (let i=1; i < lineItems.length; i++) {
                rowWriter.writeRow({GROUP_NAME:lineItems[0],YEAR:this.years[i-1],SCORE:lineItems[i]});
            }
        }
    },
    finalize: function (rowWriter, context) { /* */ },
}
$$
;
```

Finally, select the lines in your files and run them through the UDTF like this:

```
with FILE_LINES as
(
select   metadata$file_row_number   LINE_NUMBER
        ,metadata$filename          FILE_NAME
        ,$1                         LINE
from    @MY_FILES (file_format => READ_LINES) F
)
select   GROUP_NAME
        ,YEAR
        ,SCORE
        ,FILE_NAME
from     FILE_LINES F
        ,table(pivot_scores(LINE_NUMBER::float, FILE_NAME, F.LINE) over (partition by FILE_NAME order by LINE_NUMBER)) TF
;
```

I created two files to test this. File1 is your file based on the sample table, and File2 is a new one with an additional year (2020) for testing. Here is the result:

| GROUP_NAME | YEAR | SCORE | FILE_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | 2020 | 54.9 | File2.txt.gz |
| Group A | 2021 | 55.3 | File2.txt.gz |
| Group A | 2022 | 55.7 | File2.txt.gz |
| Group A | 2023 | 11.1 | File2.txt.gz |
| Group B | 2020 | 91.3 | File2.txt.gz |
| Group B | 2021 | 82.7 | File2.txt.gz |
| Group B | 2022 | 89.6 | File2.txt.gz |
| Group B | 2023 | 11.1 | File2.txt.gz |
| Group C | 2020 | 12.3 | File2.txt.gz |
| Group C | 2021 | 12.3 | File2.txt.gz |
| Group C | 2022 | 12.4 | File2.txt.gz |
| Group C | 2023 | 11.1 | File2.txt.gz |
| Group A | 2021 | 54.9 | File1.txt.gz |
| Group A | 2022 | 55.3 | File1.txt.gz |
| Group A | 2023 | 55.7 | File1.txt.gz |
| Group B | 2021 | 91.3 | File1.txt.gz |
| Group B | 2022 | 82.7 | File1.txt.gz |
| Group B | 2023 | 89.6 | File1.txt.gz |